# An application of the Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a Banach Space $X$, $y\notin Y$, $L=y+Y$, $x\notin L$. Show that there exists $f\in X^{*}$ such that $f(x)\neq f(z)$ for every $z\in L$.

Could somebody help me? Thank you.

What I have done: Since $Y$ is closed there exists $g\in X^{*}$ such that $g(y)=1$ and $ g(s)=0$ for every $ s\in Y$ (so $Y$ is contained in the kernel of g). Let $z\in L$, then $z=y+t$ for some $t\in Y$. Therefore $g(z)=1$. This implies that the kernel of $g$ is contained in the complement of $L$.
Now, assume $g(x)=g(z)$ for some $z\in L$. Then, $g(x)=1$ and  $x-y$ is in the kernel of $g$... I could't see the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Since $Y$ is closed, if we define $Y^\star=Y\cup\mathbb{R}(y-x)$, then $Y^\star$ is closed too. Let $\varphi\in(Y^\star)'$ the (bounded) linear form whose kernel is $Y$ and such that $\varphi(y-x)=1$. Then, by the Hahn-Banach theorem, you can extend $\varphi$ to a bounded linear form $F\in X'$. If $z\in L$, then $z=y+y'$, for some $y'\in Y$. Then\begin{align}f(x)-f(z)&=f(x-z)\\&=f(x-y-y')\\&=f(x-y)-f(y')\\&=1-0\\&\neq0.\end{align}

Comment: @user512913 If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.